# Object of class PDO could not be converted to string

Tags: php, oop

The error referenced in the title is occurring (apparently) on line 33. As a side note, if you have any recommendations on ways I could optimize this, or just general suggestions, I'm all ears.  Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('config.php');

$filename = htmlentities($_FILES['file']['name']);
$tmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];    
$file = $_FILES['file'];

class connect {

    public function dbConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) {

        try {
            global $dbcon;
            $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class upload Extends connect {
    public function uploadFile($dbcon, $filename, $filesize, $filetype, $file) {

        if ($filesize > 2000000) {
            echo "File too large!";
        }
        elseif ($filesize <= 2000000) {
            $stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->$dbcon->bindParam(1, $filename);
            $stmt->$dbcon->bindParam(2, $filetype);
            $stmt->$dbcon->bindParam(3, $filesize);
            $stmt->$dbcon->bindParam(4, $file);
            $stmt->$dbcon->execute();
            $stmt->$dbcon->close();
            echo "File uploaded!";
        }
        else {
            echo "Unexpected error! Please try again!";
        }
    }
}
$con = new connect;
$con->dbConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

$exec = new upload;
$exec->uploadFile($dbcon, $filename, $filesize, $filetype, $file);
```

Comment: first suggestion, mark where line 33 is

Comment: `global`? Why globalizing the variable?!

Comment: Why are you using global $dbcon;

Comment: Line 33:

            $stmt->$dbcon->bindParam(1, $filename);

@Truth Why not? Could you tell me why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @DustinL.: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```
$stmt->bindParam();
```

Drop `$dbcon` from `$stmt->$dbcon->bindParam()`.